# iterate through dicts of lists + add up values of identical keys

Tags: python, sorting, iteration

I have a data structure like this :

```
[
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 1 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 2 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "blue", "value" : 1 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "yellow", "value" : 3 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "blue", "value" : 5 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "blue", "value" : 8 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 2 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 3 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 6 }  },
]
```

The idea is I would like to iterate through it and when at least 2 `"subkeys"` are the same, fire off `some_event()`, which would add up the values from those consecutive objects, until it hits a different `"subkey"` again.

For example, the first and second dicts should fire off `some_event()` with values `2+1` added. Then nothing happens with the third (blue) nor fourth (yellow) lines, fifth and sixth (blue) fire off `some_event()` with values `5+8`, etc.

thanks!

Comment: Do you want only consecutive runs?  Or should `some_event()` be triggered on the 3rd and 5th dicts?

Comment: Only consecutive dicts - basically 1 and 2, 5 and 6, and 7,8,9.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind 1+2, 3+4, 5+6 and 7+8+9. Why does the last group contain three elements while the other contain two?

Comment: Do you actually have a list of dicts all containing one and the same key?

Comment: yes. the dicts also have a few other keys, which I omitted here since they aren't relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

L = [
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 1 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 2 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "blue", "value" : 1 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "yellow", "value" : 3 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "blue", "value" : 5 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "blue", "value" : 8 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 2 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 3 }  },
    { "key" : { "subkey" : "red", "value" : 6 }  },
]


def some_event(*args):
    print args, sum(args)


for k, g in groupby(L, key=lambda x:x["key"]["subkey"]):
    g = list(g)
    if len(g) > 1:
        some_event(*(i["key"]["value"] for i in g))
```

Comment: `len(x) > 1` should be `len(g) > 1`

Comment: Great! Why does g need to be a list?

Comment: Because the group returned by `groupby` is an iterator (see the [doc](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby))

Comment: @L-R, it's convenient to convert `g` to a list since we need to check that there is more than one item _and_ iterate over it later. If `g` was very long it may be worth using `itertools.tee` with `itertools.islice` to check there is at least 2 items without consuming the whole generator.